# Ngrok Minecraft Server kicks players as soon as they join

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

As soon as a player joins my ngrok server (which had worked in the past) he gets kicked almost as soon as they join.

Comment: Does it give a kick reason in the console or the client?

Comment: Are you running ngrok and mc server on your local machine?